# How do I get a specific line of a file using 'cat' command?

Tags: unix, grep, lines, cat

I have a text file with a lot of mda5 hashes. I need to get only the hash of my file as output.  I've tried `cat mda5hashes.txt | grep manual12.pdf`, but I have this promt:

```
manual12          917NJvfNj6uY237fjzmso38djr7s
```

How can I get only the hash as prompt, and the number of line in which is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk can do this very simply
Assuming that `manual12` occures at the begining of the line

```
awk '/^manual12/{print NR,$2}' mda5hashes.txt
```

will give the output as

```
1      917NJvfNj6uY237fjzmso38djr7s
```

What it does?

awk uses a format `pattern{action}`

That is when the line matches the pattern, the action is performed.

Here the action is to print the second `$2` column delimited by space(by default)

When pattern matches `manual12` in the line the hash part is printed

Comment: OP also wanted the line number, but I don't know awk well enough to do that.

Comment: Sweet! I should really learn awk when I have the time, your solution is much nicer than mine.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -n` will print line numbers with the match. You can translate the first colon produced by grep and all other whitespace to a single space with `sed 's/:/ /;s/\s\s*/ /g'`. You then want the first and third section, which can be achieved with `cut -d ' ' -f 2 --complement`

Chaining these all together, you would get something like:

`cat mda5hashes.txt | grep -n manual12 | sed 's/:/ /;s/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 --complement`

I'm sure somebody could replace the sed + cut combo with a perl or awk one-liner, though.

Comment: **awk '/manual12/{ print $2 }'  mda5hashes.txt** explanation: search for line containing 'manual12' then print second field of that line(record).

Comment: **awk '/manual12/{ print NR,$2 }'  mda5hashes.txt** explanation: search for line containing 'manual12' then print the line number and second field of that line(record).

Answer (score 0):

This looks OK

```
cat -n | grep manual | awk '{$2=""}1'
```

or

```
nl | grep manual | awk '{$2=""}1'
```